Converting 6-15p to a 6-20p receptacle for "through the wall" air/heating unit
How do we safely convert a dedicated 6-15p to a 6-20p receptacle? This outlet is for our "through the wall" air/heating unit, which no longer works. Current replacement units have a 6-20p plug type. The outlet is on a separate/dedicated breaker.

Is the existing wiring already 12AWG or?

The 20 means twenty amps.  Unless you are very lucky and already have 12 gauge wire, you need to change the wire, the breaker, and the receptacle.

Thank you...we aren't able to determine the gauge wire, but it's looking like an electrician will need to be involved :)

The wire gauge is printed on the wire/cable every ~12 inches.  The breaker and receptacle are easy to replace if you are comfortable.  The wire might be easy if in the open or a pain in the neck(or lower) if in the walls.  The wires/breaker will depend on what the new units take.  More than 12 amps/2880 watts and you need to change to 20 amps

If it's the only outlet on the circuit, then by code you do NOT have 12ga, as 15a receptacles are only allowed on 20a circuits when they are not the only outlet on the circuit.

Thank you for all the info!

@SortofDamocles No! That is unlikely because an electrician is not likely to spend on 12 AWG wire when 14 AWG will do. But it is possible and code compliant to use 12 AWG wire on a 15A circuit.
